# Why am I getting ubuntu option in boot menu(Image included ) even after I have deleted the Ubuntu partition?

Tags: dual-boot, uninstall

I was unsuccessful to install ubuntu, hence I deleted the partition.

[image: This is the image of the boot menu]

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete grub from the EFI System partition.

In the EFI partition, find the folder /efi/ubuntu/ and delete it.